# How to explain indistinguishability obfuscation (iO) to my grandmother?

Tags: obfuscation, indistinguishability

At the risk of oversimplification, how do I explain indistinguishability obfuscation (iO) to my grandmother?

Comment: What kind of prior knowledge do you want to assume for your grandmother (assuming this is not a metaphor)? In what context is it necessary / useful for her to learn about iO, or rather in what context did this request originate? Is a basic understanding of the definition sufficient or should it also be put into some specific context as to how that might be usefully applied? (The definition itself tends to make a "useless" impression)

Comment: I wish to explain to her in a way that is both abstract and concrete -- perhaps by way of an analogy?

Comment: It depends, how much does your grandmother know about multilinear maps?

Comment: I think OP is looking for the iO-equivalent of the zero-knowledge secret cave passthrough (e.g. https://mart-e.be/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/vote2.jpg), as in, without much (if any) mathematical foundation.

If that's the case, I fear that this question might be unanswerable. Would be a shame to close the question though, I really like it :'-)

Comment: @RubenDeSmet the issue is that iO already seems useless at first (and second) glance when looking at the formal definition. When you try to explain it using a metaphor it gets worse.

Comment: What about using an equivalent notion; the best-possible obfuscation? (https://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2007/43920194/43920194.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

iO removes all metadata from the program.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think any of my grandparents have a good (if any) notion of "metadata", "programme" or even "to remove".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51034)

Comment: @kelalaka I disagree. It is clearly an attempt to answer the question. It is a very bad, and arguably incorrect, answer but an answer nonetheless.